Unexpected table locked error when other statement fetches rows
Quite strange behavior of SQLite3:
Simple C program fetching rows from one table and creating another temp table and then dropping the second table, we get the error 6 "database table is locked"
What I am missing here?
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sqlite3.h>

static sqlite3 *conn;

static void check_error(int ln, int s)
{
    if (s != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr,">> Error (line %d): %d  %s\n", ln, sqlite3_errcode(conn), sqlite3_errmsg(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s = 0;
    char * msg;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt1 = NULL;

    s = sqlite3_open_v2(":memory:", &conn, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_exec(conn, "create table tab1 ( pk integer, name varchar(50) )", NULL, NULL, &msg);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_exec(conn, "insert into tab1 values ( 101, 'aaa' )", NULL, NULL, &msg);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);
    s = sqlite3_exec(conn, "insert into tab1 values ( 102, 'bbbbb' )", NULL, NULL, &msg);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_prepare_v2(conn, "select * from tab1 order by pk", -1, &stmt1, NULL);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_step(stmt1);
    if (s != SQLITE_ROW) check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_exec(conn, "create temp table tt1 ( pk integer, name varchar(50) )", NULL, NULL, &msg);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    s = sqlite3_exec(conn, "drop table tt1", NULL, NULL, &msg);
    check_error(__LINE__,s);

    return 0;
}

On Linux Debian 12:
$ sqlite3 --version
3.40.1 2022-12-28 14:03:47 df5c253c0b3dd24916e4ec7cf77d3db5294cc9fd45ae7b9c5e82ad8197f3alt1

$ gcc -o sqlite3_test1.bin sqlite3_test1.c -lsqlite3 && ./sqlite3_test1.bin 
>> Error (line 42): 6  database table is locked

Any idea?

Just downloaded and compiled SQLite3 3.47.2 - same issue.

Probably need to reset the in-progress prepared statement first.
